# Does battle level affect mercenaries?

Tags: endless-battle

When increasing your battle level in [Endless Battle](http://www.kruv.net/endlessBattle.html) the monsters get stronger and the drops get better.  Both of these are specific to the player's interaction in the battles.

Does having the battle level set higher also increase the Gold Per Second gained from mercenaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this and no it does not.

I have 5 footmen hired with no upgrades. Cycling between battle level 1-3 my GPS output remains at 0.51